# Flatmap concurrency limit (like bacon.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp, rxjs

I'm looking at the RxJS docs for something like bacon's `flatMapWithConcurrencyLimit`, but don't see anything. Any idea if it's available in Rx or not?

Answer (score 2):

In Rx.NET there's a [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211914(v=vs.103).aspx) operator that accepts a maximum concurrency parameter.  Essentially, its semantics are the same as `SelectMany` (a.k.a., **FlatMap**) with a concurrency limit.

It seems that Rx.JS defines this overload as well: [merge](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/mergeproto.js).

Answer (score 0):

a simpler option without pulling an entire library of streams/observables: https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue